# Input seems to be expecting an integer instead of string

Tags: input

I'm new to working in terminal (Mac, bash) and starting a tutorial, but I don't get the results that are expected.
Here's my code in atom.

```
print('Hello, python')
name = input('What is your name? ')
print name
```

And here's what I get after entering Tim  (or after entering anything other than and integer)

```
Hello, python
What is your name? Tim
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "max2.py", line 2, in <module>
    name = input('What is your name? ')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Tim' is not defined
```

If I enter an integer it works fine.

```
Hello, python
What is your name? 4
4
```

My understanding is that input takes the user input and puts it in a string. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, but you are running it through the wrong version of Python. The `input()` function is different between Python 2 and Python 3.

| Function | Python 2 | Python 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `input()` | Reads and evaluates a Python expression | Reads a string |
| `raw_input()` | Reads a string | Doesn't exist, use input() |

Since Python 2 is practically obsolete, you should make sure that your script is being invoked through `python3` and not through just "python" (which is different from OS to OS but *usually* means Python 2).

For example, if your script has a `#!` line (and you're running it via `./myscript.py`) then change that line to specify "python3".

(However, I'm actually not sure whether macOS even *comes with* Python 3. You may need to install it through Homebrew or whatever else they use on macOS.)

Also note that the `print` syntax is also very different between the two. You're using the correct syntax for Python 3, but it is only by coincidence that `print(x)` with *one* parameter works the same way in both versions.